# Configurar Python para ambientes virtuales

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

he instalado python3 y permite agregar la variable de entorno global, ahora que cuando empece a ver entornos virtuales lo que instalo por medio de pip todo me queda global y obvio las complicaciones que trae todo esto. que debo de hacer eliminar el path de la variable global de python3? o que me recomiendan, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿activas el entorno virtual antes de usarlo? ¿que sistema operativo usas?

Comment: Hola Patricio, de tanto revisar no me accionaba el entorno virtual con bash y lo realice directamente con la termina de windows y funciono de una, no se si es un error o que pero asi solucione, gracias por contestar